# How to get specific parameter in tr tag and td value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get tr parameters like "data-value" and want to get td value in same row.This progress runs for each rows.

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Field</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>No</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ftid">
        <tr class="selected-field" data-value="timeoriginalestimate">
            <td></td>
            <td>Original Estimate</td>
            <td>System field</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><p>1</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="selected-field" data-value="timeoriginalestimate">
            <td></td>
            <td>Original Estimate</td>
            <td>System field</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><p>2</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="selected-field" data-value="timeoriginalestimate">
            <td></td>
            <td>Original Estimate</td>
            <td>System field</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><p>3</p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var len=cells.length;

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log(cells[i].innerHTML);
    }
</script>
```

### This code return;

-blank-value-

Original Estimate

System Field

-blank-value-

1

...

### But i want to;

timeoriginalestimate(data-value's value)

Original Estimate

1

....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating through all the *td*'s and printing `textContent` from them. You have to target only the specific *td* from the current *tr* element.

You can  try with `querySelectorAll()`, `querySelector()` and `getAttribute()`

```js
var tr = document.querySelectorAll('#table tbody tr');

for (var i=0; i<tr.length; i++){
  console.log(tr[i].getAttribute('data-value'));
  console.log(tr[i].querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent);
  console.log(tr[i].querySelector('td:nth-child(5) p').textContent);
  console.log('--------');
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Field</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>No</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ftid">
        <tr class="selected-field" data-value="timeoriginalestimate">
            <td></td>
            <td>Original Estimate</td>
            <td>System field</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><p>1</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="selected-field" data-value="timeoriginalestimate">
            <td></td>
            <td>Original Estimate</td>
            <td>System field</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><p>2</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="selected-field" data-value="timeoriginalestimate">
            <td></td>
            <td>Original Estimate</td>
            <td>System field</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><p>3</p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```